# How google identifies text colour and background?

Tags: colors, seo, web-crawler, background-color

Google identifies the text colours from coding like if black it will be coded with #000000, and Google read this code and identifies that it is black colour,

However if colour in coding is black ie #000000, and with some other plugin I change it to white in appearance without changing coding.

In this condition Google can able to identify the difference between white and black text? or it will considered black as what in mention coding of text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Search Console to fetch and render.](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6066468?hl=en) This will show you both what a normal browser can see and how Googlebot sees a page.

Comment: thanks for reply but My friend Google updates its algorithms day by day but not updated its webmaster, it just for beginners, I mean How google identifies colors, did you get my point??

Comment: You're asking if I know the Google algorithm. No one does. All we have are educated guesses and the tools they offer us via Webmaster.

Comment: Yes you are right, Google know our text on website very clearly, if we have bold text google can easily identifies it because it wraps with <b></b> tag, so similarly how google see colours, due to codes of colours?? or anything else??